# How to print multiple values in C# method?

Tags: c#, methods

I want to print values from GetStudentInformation() method through PrintStudentDetails(string first, string last, string birthday) method. Please view the code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Module3_HomeWork
{
    class Program
    {
        static void GetStudentInformation()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the student's first name: ");
            string firstName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the student's last name: ");
            string lastName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the student's birthdate: ");
            DateTime birthdate = Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the student's address line 1: ");
            string add1 = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the student's address line 2: ");
            string add2 = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the student's city: ");
            string city = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the student's state: ");
            string state = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the student's zip code: ");
            int zip = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the student's country: ");
            string country = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static void PrintStudentDetails(string first, string last, string birthday)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} was born on: {2}", first, last, birthday);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetStudentInformation();
            PrintStudentDetails(first, last, birthday);
        }

        public static string first { get; set; }

        public static string last { get; set; }

        public static string birthday { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How can i print values using only methods not class? I've researched on it and found out about `out` and `ref` , any help or guidance will be much appreciated.

Regards

Comment: use properties instead of local variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is to input first name, last name and birth date and then output them, you can change the following three lines:

```
string firstName = Console.ReadLine();
string lastName = Console.ReadLine();
DateTime birthdate = Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine());
```

to the following:

```
first = Console.ReadLine();
last = Console.ReadLine();
birthday = Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine());
```

then your program should run as you expect.

But since you mentioned `out` and `ref`, perhaps what you really want is the following:

```
class Program
{
    static void GetStudentInformation(out string first, out string last, out string birthday)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the student's first name: ");
        first = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the student's last name: ");
        last = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the student's birthdate: ");
        birthday = Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    static void PrintStudentDetails(string first, string last, string birthday)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} was born on: {2}", first, last, birthday);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string first, last, birthday;
        GetStudentInformation(out first, out last, out birthday);
        PrintStudentDetails(first, last, birthday);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what did you mean by print value only by method not class. But I guess below example can help you out.

```
void PrintDetails(ref string s1, ref string s2, ref string s3)
{ 
  s1 = "Some text goes here";
  s2 = myNumber.ToString();
  s3 = "some more text";
}
```

Now while calling this function just use below syntax:

```
public void SomeOtherFunction()
{
  string sMyValue1 = null;
  string sMyValue2 = null;
  string sMyValue3 = null;

  PrintDetails(sMyValue1, sMyValue2, sMyValue3);
  //Now you have all the values inside your local variable. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `out` or `ref` keyword will help you return multiple values from method if you really want it to do it that way, but using properties is probably a better solution. Anyways, this is how it would look like using `out` keyword:

```
static void GetStudentInformation(out string firstName, out string lastName, out DateTime birthDate,
    out string add1, out string add2, out string city, out string state, out int zip, out string country)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the student's first name: ");
    firstName = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the student's last name: ");
    lastName = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the student's birthdate: ");
    birthDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the student's address line 1: ");
    add1 = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the student's address line 2: ");
    add2 = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the student's city: ");
    city = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the student's state: ");
    state = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the student's zip code: ");
    zip = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the student's country: ");
    country = Console.ReadLine();
}
static void PrintStudentDetails(string first, string last, string birthday)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} was born on: {2}", first, last, birthday);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string firstName, lastName, add1, add2, city, state, country;
    DateTime birthDate;
    int zip;

    GetStudentInformation(out firstName, out lastName, out birthDate, out add1, out add2, out city, out state, out zip, out country);
    PrintStudentDetails(firstName, lastName, birthDate.ToShortDateString());
}
```

You could also replace all out keywords with `ref` keywords and you would get the same effect. You would just need to initialize your variables to some value before passing them by ref to GetStudentInformation method.